# I cant get to work my movement script for unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

*I followed a tutorial for a simple 2d character controller, here is the code:*

```
using UnityEngine;
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private float speed;
private Rigidbody2D body;

private void awake()
{
    body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

private void Update()
{
    body.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed, body.velocity.y);
}
```

}

*I get this error every frame (the update function)*:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
PlayerMovement.Update () (at Assets/scripts/PlayerMovement.cs:15)

*The error its at line 15, where is the "body.velocity" thing, Anyone knows where is the problem?*

Comment: Add a check for the 'body', it can be equal to null.

Comment: because i specified that Rigidbody2D is "body", i cant comprehend

Comment: You have a typo its `Awake` not `awake`, method names are case sensitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, `body` is null, because the component it's referencing has not been defined. You have to attach a `Rigidbody2D` component to the Game Object that your script is sitting on.

---

Since this script requires a `Rigidbody2D` to work, you can add a line that will automatically create it on the Game Object when your script is added. It goes at the top of the class definition, like so:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))] // <- This is what I'm talking about.
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    // To save space, I didn't paste the rest of your code.
    // ...
}
```

[View official documentation on `RequireComponent[]`.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RequireComponent.html)

> When you add a script which uses RequireComponent to a GameObject, the required component will automatically be added to the GameObject. Note that RequireComponent only checks for missing dependencies during the moment the component is added to the GameObject. Existing instances of the component whose GameObject lacks the new dependencies will not have those dependencies added automatically.

---

Alternatively, you can remove the code inside your `Awake()` method that fetches the component, and instead drag-and-drop the component in the inspector.

This is the recommended way to do things, because it makes your script more flexible: you won't have to rewrite it when there comes a time that the `Rigidbody2D` component needs to be attached to a different Game Object than your `PlayerMovement`. (This will happen surprisingly often.)